# Facebook: prolongating auth token lifetime?

Tags: facebook, oauth

I'm working on application that should make posts on behalf of user. Post can be in some very distant time (like a month or even half year). From what I see in FB developers documentation there's no obvious way to make `auth_token` be valid for so long. At the moment I ask user for login and password then application authorizes itself. Ugly hack. I want to avoid that. Is that possible?

Comment: That’s not only an “ugly hack”, it’s also against FB’s terms. You can prolong a user access token to be valid for up to 60 days, and normally that should be enough – after that, it can be expected that the user would be willing to visit your app again if they still want it to post on their behalf. (Certain kinds of posting actions are also possible with the app access token, after the user has given the app permission once.)

Comment: @CBroe how do I prolong it? Could you also please provide a link to docs?

Comment: You have not looked through the docs at all, have you? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending

Comment: @CBroe Ive been reading PHP SDK docs only :( Thank you for link, it answers all my questions.